# Spotfire report appearing blank when published

Tags: report, publishing, spotfire

I have created a report in Spotfire that appears fine in the software itself but when accessed through our web player it just presents a blank screen.

I have created another report, which works perfectly, using the same data table and the connection strings and login details are the same.

I've asked everyone here that uses Spotfire and nobody has seen the problem before.   Any suggestions on what the problem may be or where I might try looking would be greatly appreciated!!

B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to those who looked at my quetsion - sorry it was a bit vague!   Turns out it was a problem with the complexity of the report vs. the capability of our web player!